# SQL special group by on list of strings ending with *

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, group-by

I would like to perform a "special group by" on strings with SQL language, some ending with "*". I use postgresql.
I can not clearly formulate this problem, even if I have partially solved it, with select, union and nested queries which are not elegant.

For exemple :

1) INPUT : I have a list of strings :

```
thestrings
varchar(9)
--------------
1000
1000-0001
1000-0002
2000*
2000-0001
2000-0002
3000*
3000-00*
3000-0001
3000-0002
```

2) OUTPUT : That I would like my "special group by" return  :

```
1000
1000-0001
1000-0002
2000*
3000*
```

Because 2000-0001 and 2000-0002 are include in 2000*, 
and because 3000-00*,  3000-0001 and  3000-0002 are includes in 3000*

3)  SQL query I do :

```
SELECT every strings ending with *
UNION
SELECT every string where the begining  NOT IN  (SELECT every string ending with *)   <-- with multiple inelegant left functions and NOT IN subqueries
```

4) That what I'm doing return :

```
1000
1000-0001
1000-0002
2000*
3000*
3000-00* <-- the problem
```

The problem is : **3000-00*** staying in my result.

So my question is :
How can I generalize my problem? to remove all string who have a same begining string in the list (ending with *) ?
I think of regular expressions, but how to pass a list from a select in a regex ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only strings for which no master string exists in the table:

```
select str
from mytable
where not exists 
(
  select *
  from mytable master
  where master.str like '%*'
  and master.str <> mytable.str
  and rtrim(mytable.str, '*') like rtrim(master.str, '*') || '%'
);
```

Comment: The solution seems works also ! Thank you. On 15000 inputs, it output 5700 and make 0m38s. Best at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only one general pattern can match any given string, the following should do what you want:

```
select coalesce(tpat.thestring, t.thestring) as thestring
from t left join
     t tpat
     on t.thestring like replace(tpat.thestring, '*', '%') and
        t.thestring <> tpat.thestring
group by coalesce(tpat.thestring, t.thestring);
```

However, that is not your case.  However, you can adjust this with `distinct on`:

```
  select distinct on (t.thestring) coalesce(tpat.thestring, t.thestring)
  from t left join
       t tpat
       on t.thestring like replace(tpat.thestring, '*', '%') and
          t.thestring <> tpat.thestring
  order by t.thestring, length(tpat.thestring)
```

Comment: The first solution seems works ! Thank you. On 15000 inputs, it output 5800 and make 1m38.